# Expanding an image from a thumbnail in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

So I have a simple application in which I am taking an image with the camera and then loading the images into a `GridView`, when I click on the `GridView` it must open a bigger version of that image. I cannot get the image to open bigger.

The problem is that I have no reference to that image when passing it to the `Activity` which makes the image bigger. Code is below.

MainActivity.java

```
protected static final String EXTRA_RES_ID = "POS";
private ArrayList<String> mThumbIdsSelfies = new ArrayList<String>();

if(populateArrayList())
{
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    // Create a new ImageAdapter and set it as the Adapter for this GridView
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mThumbIdsSelfies));

    // Set an setOnItemClickListener on the GridView
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id)
        {

            //Create an Intent to start the ImageViewActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageViewActivity.class);

            // Add the ID of the thumbnail to display as an Intent Extra
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RES_ID, (int) id);

            // Start the ImageViewActivity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private boolean populateArrayList()
{
    File dir = getAlbumDir();
    //Bitmap myBitmap;

    if (dir.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            //myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[i].toString());
            mThumbIdsSelfies.add(files[i].toString());
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

ImageViewActivity.java - This is the one that makes the image bigger

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the Intent used to start this Activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // Make a new ImageView
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

        // Get the ID of the image to display and set it as the image for this ImageView
        imageView.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_RES_ID, 0));

        setContentView(imageView);
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private static final int PADDING = 8;
    private static final int WIDTH = 250;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 250;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mThumbIds;

    // Store the list of image IDs
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, List<String> ids) 
    {
        mContext = c;
        this.mThumbIds = ids;
    }

    // Return the number of items in the Adapter
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return mThumbIds.size();
    }

    // Return the data item at position
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return mThumbIds.get(position);
    }

    // Will get called to provide the ID that
    // is passed to OnItemClickListener.onItemClick()
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return mThumbIds.indexOf(position);
    }

    // Return an ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

        // if convertView's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        if (imageView == null) 
        {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            imageView.setPadding(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }

        //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds.get(position));
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mThumbIds.get(position));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

So the problem with the above function is that I cannot use getItemId as it does not return a long, rather it returns a string and I have no way of getting something useful from it.

The other thing I have tried is passing the bitmap image as an extra in my bundle and reading it on the other side, still I have no luck in getting the actual image to display.

Comment: Using .setImageResource() does not make sense as you are not using images from resources to begin with. getItemId() returns a long so why are you talking differently? Just pass the path to the image in the intent to the next activity and load the image from that path as you do in getView() also.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out, so here is what I did.

MainActivity.java - Changed the following line

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RES_ID, mThumbIdsSelfies.get(position)/*(int) id*/);
```

ImageViewActivity.java

```
String s = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_RES_ID);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

So those changes finally helped me, all I had to do was pass a string reference to the file location of the thumbnail I just clicked on. Then in the Activity that enlarges that image, I had to get that string reference and generate a bitmap out of it and then set that bitmap to the imageView.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `mThumbIdsSelfies` is an `ArrayList` of the image paths you can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RES_ID, mThumbIdsSelfies[position]);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then retrieve it in your `Activity`(`ImageViewActivity`) and use it as you do in your adapter's `getView()` method.

Comment: I tried doing this in some way an form, but had little success. Figured it out though.